# How to call rvalue methods of members?

Tags: c++, rvalue

I'm writing a class (`Interface`), which encapsulates a class (`Impl`) which happens to have an rvalue function (see `Impl::Close`).

```
class Impl
{
public:
    /// Called from Dtor.
    /// You can't reuse this after it has been closed
    /// Therefore && added so need temporary / rvalue ref.
    void Close(int why) && noexcept { /*...*/ }
};



class Interface
{
public:
    void Close(int why) && noexcept { _i.Close(why); }
private:
    Impl _i;
};
```

Lintian gives me:

> error: 'this' argument to member function 'Close' is an lvalue, but function has rvalue ref-qualifier

g++ gives me:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Interface::Close(int) &&’:
main.cpp:15:51: error: passing ‘Impl’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   15 |     void Close(int why) && noexcept { _i.Close(why); }
      |                                                   ^
main.cpp:4:10: note:   in call to ‘void Impl::Close(int) &&’
    7 |     void Close(int why) && noexcept { }
      |
```

I don't really understand this feedback.  I get that the object doesn't really exist after calling `Close` so I'm not sure why the `&&` doesn't make sense in both `Interface` and the `Impl`.

Comment: `this` being a temporary does not necessarily imply that all members are. Consider that members could be reference, or themself hold a reference

Comment: I'm very confused by your decision to make `Interface::Close()` r-value qualified because the object should not be used afterwards. Do you expect your users to call the method this way: `std::move(obj).Close();`? And if so, why? To me, `&&` qualification implies that something would be 'stolen' from the object like a buffer for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_i` itself is still an *lvalue*, so it needs to be converted to an rvalue to call its rvalue-qualified member function

```
void Close(int why) && noexcept { std::move(_i).Close(why); }
```

Comment: That answer was so fast, SO won't let me accept it for another 4 minutes.  I had tried std::move around the whole void return, so now it makes sense to me.  Thanks